# Merging topoJSON layers with the same name in different files

Tags: topojson

I'm trying to use NaturalEarth cultural vector data to create a topoJSON file with two layers:

- US states
- World countries

I make the countries topojson file out of the Natural Earth subunits map, omitting the USA, then I use the Natural Earth states map to make a file that contains US states and the USA itself in a layer called "countries". Now, I have two topojson files, each with a layer called "countries". How can I merge these two files into a single one that has a "countries" layer containing the contents of both of their "countries" layers?

Just calling topojson on the files combines them but overwrites one instance of "countries" with another.

I've currently just been using the topojson CLI, but have no problem switching to using the server API if I need to.

**Edit:** I've resolved the issue by manually concatenating the relevant objects inside topojson files, but am still interested in knowing if there is a solution in the topojson module that I've overlooked.

Comment: Add the layers to QGIS and then export them =)